# Cannot show single view using Material Component in Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5, angular2-routing, angular2-forms, angular2-services

I am working with a project using Angular 5, Material Component & firebase for data base purposes. I have a data in material grid of whole table i.e Client. I am clicking in view icon which have to show me single client data in child component but material table need to bind with data source but I cannot bind single client date to data source. 
After clicking onView function it navigate to client-detail.component

> client.component.html

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="action">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
        <b>Action</b>
      </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let item">
                <i class="material-icons" style="cursor: pointer;" (click)="onView(item)">visibility</i>
      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
```

> client.component.ts

```
 onView(prod){
    this.router.navigate(['./',prod.prodid,'view'],{relativeTo: this.route});
  }
```

> client-detail.component.ts

```
displayedColumns = ['no', 'name', 'cemail', 'address', 'country', 'projects', 'proposallist', 'quotationlist'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Client>();
  dataProject = new MatTableDataSource<Project>();

  projects: AngularFirestoreCollection<any> = this.pro.collection('project');
  projectsarray: Array<any>;
  dataproject = this.projects.valueChanges();

  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    filterValue = filterValue.trim(); 
    filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase(); 
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
  }

  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    this.clientservice.getClient().subscribe(data => {
      this.dataSource.data = data;
    })
  }
```

Comment: you can use a sharedservice between two components to show details of clicked row in other component

Comment: @yer I did it already but when I called clientservice.getClient() method its shows error because getClient() method took arguments but here in datatable it cannot take any argument. This is the main issue.